# Is a sequence keeps the properties of a function

Tags: calculus

I am not sure if the following statement is true:
Let $f$ be a function in $(0,\infty)$ monotonically increasing and let $A_n$ be a sequence that converges to infinity, the. $f(A_n)$ is also monotonically increasing.
I tried to prove it it didn't go well, my question is even more general.
For example if $f$ is bounded, $f(A_n)$ is also bounded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the counterexample $f(x)=x$ and $a_n=n+42\cdot (-1)^n$.

If $f$ is bounded, say $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ then of course also $|f(a_n)|<M$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ as $a_n\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I would like to add a similar question: Let f,g,h be functions so f<g<h in an interval of a, then for any sequence An that converges to a follows that f(An)<g(An)<h(An).